# jflot X-Axis is causing data to be reordered

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flot

Hi I am using JFlot to graph data for each minute over a 5 hour period.

If it is currently 12am on 01/10/2013, the data will return values from 7pm on 01/09/2013 until now.

The issue is that the data doesn't return the date and the users don't want to see the date on the x-axis.

My minute value is returned as an integer that represents the current minute of the day. The data is returned in the proper order however, jflot seems to reorder it based on the numeric value of the x-axis.

Here is an example
1440 is 11:59pm
while 30 would 12:30am

The reason this causes an issue is at midnight the line chart will start plotting the values on the left, rather than continue from the previous day.

**GOOD**

> 1430,1431,1432,1433,1434,1435,1436,1437,1438,1439,1440,00,01,02,03,04,05

**BAD**

> 00,01,02,03,04,05,1430,1431,1432,1433,1434,1435,1436,1437,1438,1439,1440

Comment: You should use timestamps or categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about ordering at all you should use the [categories](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/index.html) plugin.

A better solution would be to ensure that your data is increasing, e.g. pre-process it so that instead of 30 you have 1470, and then provide a tickFormatter function that computes the modulo 1440 so the values are displayed in your expected range.

Comment: ahh i like the idea of increasing the time, and then using a tickformat function to change it back